# Nginx proxy keeps getting bad gateway

Tags: nginx

I am running a CentOS version 7 Virtual Machine and trying to proxy it to a subsonic server which is running on Windows Server 2012.

When I was using Apache it was working without issues but I am currently trying to do the same using Nginx but I keep getting 502 bad gateway.

I can't seem to figure what is causing this issue.

My nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.example.com;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name music.exmaple.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.67:6060/;
        proxy_redirect / http://192.168.1.67:6060/;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout   90;
        proxy_send_timeout      90;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
        proxy_buffers           32 4k;
    }
}
```

On Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName music.example.com
    ServerAlias www.music.example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^music/(.*)$ http://192.168.1.67:6060/ [P]
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.67:6060/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.67:6060/
</VirtualHost>
```

Telnet to 192.168.1.67:6060

```
Trying 192.168.1.67...
Connected to 192.168.1.67.
Escape character is '^]'.
dir
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)

Error: 400Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Error log:

> 2014/10/23 16:51:21 [crit] 11191#0: *1 connect() to 192.168.1.67:6060 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.1, server: music.example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: `"http://192.168.1.67:6060/favicon.ico"`, host: "music.example.com"

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the new server able to access the 192.168.1.67:6060 address ?

Comment: What does your error log say ? It seems connection attempt to 192.168.1.67:6060 ends up with a RESET packet being received, so either a firewall is rejecting the connection or 192.168.1.67 doesnrt have a service listening on port 6060. What's `telnet 192.168.1.67 6060` output ?

Comment: I am able to access 192.168.1.67 through the browser with no issues if that's what you mean. I have updated the telnet output on the question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it the telnet from the machine nginx is running on ? Can you post your error log too ?

Comment: Yes.That is the telnet from the machine nginx is running on. Error log has been updated in the question.

Comment: Isn't that a selinux restriction?

Comment: "Permission denied" + Centos7 = selinux : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24830777/1164809

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default SELinux prevents the web server from making outbound connections to foreign hosts.

You can change this and allow outgoing connections by setting the `httpd_can_network_connect` boolean.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```